# Compiling c code with bool without using c99 standard

Tags: c, while-loop, boolean, c99, getchar

I've tried to compile a code using a bool variable in C and I've included the stdbool header but when I compiled it I didn't specify that I want to compile it with the c99 standard (so it was compiled with ANSI C standard) but it worked anyway.
I was wondering why is that ?
Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    char name[20];
    printf("What's your name ? ");
    gets(name);
    printf("Nice to meet you %s.\n", name);
    bool exit = false;
    char c;
    printf("Do you wish to exit the program ? (Y/N) ");
    while (!exit) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '\n') {
            continue;
        }
        printf("Do you wish to exit the program ? (Y/N) ");
        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
            exit = true;
        }
    }
    printf("Have a nice day %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Also another question regarding to my code.
In the part where you are being asked if you wish to exit the program, I've tested it with the following input :
n
n
y

And for some reason it printed out to the console the question for the fourth time and I don't see why.
I've set it so if the input is Y/y the next iteration in the while loop shouldn't take place but for some reason it printed it again, could someone explain me what I did wrong ?

EDIT :
So I've edited the code a bit tried to test new things and I've noticed that with the following code if the user input is Y/y it won't come out of the loop :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    char name[20];
    printf("What's your name ? ");
    gets(name);
    char lastname[20];
    printf("%s what's your last name ? ", name);
    fgets(lastname, 20, stdin);
    int age;
    printf("%s %s what's your age? ", name, lastname);
    scanf("%d", &age);
    bool exit = false;
    char c;
    while (!exit) {
        printf("Do you wish to exit the program ? (Y/N) ");
        c = getchar();
        getchar();
        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
            exit = true;
    }
    printf("Have a nice day %s %s.\n", name, lastname);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I did it but I added a getchar() call before the while loop and tried to compile it this way and then the program worked fine, from this I assume that the fgets\scanf functions interfering with the getchar function but I'm not sure why could someone explain ?

Comment: which compiler? gcc?

Comment: Regarding the second question: put the `printf` statement before the `c = getchar();`

Comment: After `c = getchar();`, add `printf("%d\n", c);` or use a debugger to see what your are truly entering.  BTW: Should use `int c;`

Comment: @chux why I should use int c ?

Comment: Use `int` as 1) that is the type returned by `getchar()`.  2) `getchar()` typically returns one of 256 `unsigned char` and `EOF` or 257 different values.  If you save the result in a `char`, the `EOF` will be indistinguishable from one of the `unsigned char`.  By using an `int`, code can correctly code `if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || EOF) {`.  This is not your larger issue, but a secondary one.

Comment: List explicitly key-by-key, what input you use.  "n n y" is not specific enough.

Comment: @chux weird to think that getCHAR returns int, I know it can be represented by ascii but still.. and what if I take input as a char and I get EOF char ? I wasn't sure why it won't treat it as an EOF char

Comment: There is no "EOF char".  It is a condition.  Often `EOF` has the value of `-1`.  Should a character get read that has the value of 255, `getchar()` returns 255.  Assigning that to a `char` results in the value of `(char) -1`.  Should the end-of-file condition occur (or IO error), `getchar()` returns EOF (-1 assumed here) and assigns that to a `char`.  `(char) -1` is indistinguishable from `char 255`.

Comment: so because eof doesn't have an ascii code we store the value from getchar() in int so we would know if we reach eof so we wouldn't continue reading and get io error because there're no more characters left right ?

Comment: @chux But if we assume that we get USER input from console we can use char right ? Because there's no way to get EOF from user input in console. (also read my last comment forgot to mention your name, and I couldn't edit my post since 5 minutes have passed)

Comment: Yes, the 20:08 comment is exactly correct.  Your 20:15 comment is certainly incorrect as there usually _some_ key sequence that will close `stdin`.  Some systems use Ctrl-d, Ctrl-z, etc.  It depends on your console.

Comment: @chux and those key sequences are like eof ? btw thanks for explaining really helping me.

Comment: `c = getchar()` reads the newline you typed after the previous `%d` entry, and `getchar()` reads your `Y` and discards it since you didn't assign it to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most C compilers extend the base language with extensions. One such extension could be to let the `stdbool.h` work even in C90 mode. If you really want to, you can usually turn off most of the extensions with some compiler flag, e.g. for gcc use `-std=c90`. Not sure about extra headers, the file is still there after all, so it can probably be included regardless of mode.

For your second question, try stepping through the program, printing the value of `c` at each step. It should make it fairly obvious what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

About second question:

Your code deciding to leave program or not is strange, it can be done simpler way:

```
int c=0;
do{
    if(c!='\n')
        puts("Do you wish to exit the program? (Y/N) ");
    c=getchar();
}while(c!='y' && c!='Y');
```

When code is simpler, it's harder to make mistake in it.

Comment: not using do while is really my bad , but I used bool on purpose because I wanted to check what happens if I compile without using c99 standard and it compiled for some reason

Answer (score 0):

stdbool.h defines bool, true, and false for you - the header itself is not dependent on the language standard you pass in, so long as you have the header on your system. EDIT - this may only be the case for the stock osx header. gcc's header (4.8) doesn't look like it will work.

Your logic for exiting the loop doesn't look like how you describe what you want it to do. You're still testing the previous character in your y/Y section, even though you printed out the question again at that point. I suggest stepping through your code with a debugger - this will make it more clear to you what's going on. The debugger will be an incredibly important learning tool for you, now and forever. :)

You probably want something like this for your code (remove the first printf question in your code):

```
while (!exit) {
    printf("Do you wish to exit the program ? (Y/N) ");
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n') {
        continue;
    }
    if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
        exit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen on a video someone saying it's dependent on the standard are you sure its dependent if I have the header file in my system ?

Comment: If you have a compiler that supports the standard, then you ought to have the file in your include path. It's possible that your compiler would have separate includes based on the standard passed in, but I've never seen that before. My system is osx 10.9/clang. It's easy enough to go read the header, mine was pretty short and uninteresting.

Comment: stdbool.h defines bool as an alias of _Bool, and _Bool only exists in C99 or C11.

Comment: Looks like it depends on the implementation of stdbool.h. It looks like my stock stdbool.h on a osx 10.9/clang system works by adding "typedef int _Bool;". Looking at a gcc 4.8 version I also have on my system, that one doesn't look like it will work <c99.

Comment: stdbool.h from clang 3.4 also looks to be language specific. So it may just be the osx/bsd header that is an anomaly.